# Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Im new in laravel

Always get this

Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2147483656 bytes)
Error on this line

```
$arrayGejala = collect([
        substr($gejala1, 14, 1), 
        substr($gejala2, 14, 1), 
        substr($gejala3, 14, 1),
    ])->implode(',');

    $belief = DB::table('pengetahuan')->select(DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(penyakit.kode_penyakit)"), 'pengetahuan.bobot')
        ->from('pengetahuan')
        ->join('penyakit', 'pengetahuan.id_penyakit', '=', 'penyakit.id_penyakit')
        ->whereIn('pengetahuan.id_gejala', [(array)$arrayGejala[0],(array)$arrayGejala[2],(array)$arrayGejala[4]])
        ->groupBy('pengetahuan.id_gejala')
        ->get();
        
        $evidence = array();
        while ($row = $belief->first()) {
            $evidence[]=$row;
        }
```

Comment: `while ($row = $belief->first())` will result in an infinite loop. If `$belief->first()` is truthy once it will be truthy forever (the function is "pure" i.e. it doesn't change the state of the collection). You might want to do something like `$evidence = $belief->all()` instead of a loop

Answer (score 1):

Increase your maximum memory limit to 64MB in your php.ini file. Google search But could I ask why you are trying to allocate that much memory? What line of code does it fail at?

1. in your PHP.ini file, change the line in PHP.ini If your line shows 32M try 64M: **memory_limit = 64M ;** Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (64MB)
2. If you don't have access to PHP.ini try adding this to an .htaccess file: **php_value memory_limit 64M**

Comment: i want to fetch data from $belief, and the code always say the error is on 'while'

Comment: Increasing the memory limit is not a good solution.

Comment: Yeah, maybe im just gonna delete that infinte loop and find another solution. Thanks for answering guys